# How to identify the cause of entering Safe Mode?

Tags: motorola-xoom, safe-mode

I have a Motorola Xoom 3G tablet running Android 4.04 (latest system release) that has been stuck in 'safe mode' for some time now no matter how many times I restart the device.

I have been through the apps list and uninstalled anything I could remember installing recently but still the problem persists.

The device is primarily used as a wifi hotspot with my 3G internet around the house which still works fine - but I would also like to use the screen as an ereader from time to time - which the permanent 'safe mode' message gets in the way of.

Is there any way of tracing the cause of this safe mode loop?

Alternately is there a way of just getting rid of the 'safe mode' message while leaving it in safe mode?

Comment: I just performed a factory reset - lost all of my data and the device is still booting to 'safe mode' ... GRRRrrrr

Comment: No removable battery, I guess, so taking that out for a while is no option. Have you tried poking the reset hole with some paper clip or the like for at least a couple of seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a hardware fault in this particular circumstance a faulty connection between the flex cable that connects the volume buttons and the motherboard... Reseated the connector and 'safe mode' was gone next time I restarted.

Found this by trial and error - don't know of any way to narrow down the cause with the help of software.

So wish I had checked that connector before I went and wiped everything... Doh!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Spent a night to fix it. First i thought it to be a software issue.. browsed and tried infinite fixes. I tried **re seating** flex cable that connects the volume buttons and the motherboard.I tries to factory reset through boot loader. Thought of flashing a different ROM. Dint work out for me.

**Here is what worked for me.**

1. Open the back panel of the tablet.
   https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nexus+7+Power+%26+Volume+Button+Cable+Replacement/9926
2. Flip up the retaining flap on the 'power and volume button ribbon cable' connecting to the mother board. **DO NOT PULL OUT THE CABLE NOW.**   Be ready to pull out the cable.

3.Press the power button to switch on your tablet.

4.The moment you see Google logo, pull out 'power and volume button ribbon cable'. This will disconnect volume down key, which forces the tablet into bootloader.

5.Now the tablet is ON in normal mode.

6.Plug the 'power and volume button ribbon cable' into its mother board socket.

7.Close the panel and enjoy using your tablet.

Be very careful with 'power and volume button ribbon cable'. A slight twist or bend will short the connections inside the cable.

P.S : **After powering on, Try not to switch off the tablet.** The volume down key might malfunction again and your tablet might go back to boot loader. Charge it before the battery dies out. In worst case, you'll have to repeat the above steps again. Messing with the power keys cable is not always a good idea :D

The volume down key and power key combination lets you to go into boot loader. So when volume down key is malfunctioning, your tablet might go for a toss. This could be for various reasons ,

a.Volume key is abused
b. volume key cable is damaged
c. Mother board is unable to supply enough power to volume keys.
d. volume keys socket in the mother board is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you booting your Device only pressing **Power Button** , without pressing any additional button like **Volume Up , Volume Down , Home button**

If the device keeps going automatically to Safe Mode , probably one Application is causing this or is a Hardware problem...

**Note**

Don't flash any custom rom or kernel ,  that your Device doesn't meet the hardware requirements